# What is the cutting point of two distributions?

Tags: statistics, bayesian, distribution-tails

I just want to know what is the cutting point between the predictive bayesian distribution and the predictive frequentist distribution (plugin) (the one that uses the MLE). I will only consider distributions with positive support.

This is my attempt:

Let $x_f^{*}$ be the point such that

\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty f (x_f^{*} \mid \theta) \pi(\theta\mid \textbf{x}) \, d\theta = f(x_f^{*}\mid\hat{\theta}) \\[10pt]
\iff & \int_0^\infty f (x_f^{*} \mid \theta)\pi(\theta\mid\textbf{x}) \, d\theta - f(x_f^{*}\mid\hat{\theta}) = 0 \\[10pt]
\iff & \int_0^\infty f (x_f^{*} \mid \theta)\pi(\theta\mid\textbf{x}) \, d\theta - \int_0^\infty f(x_f^{*}\mid\hat{\theta})\pi(\theta\mid\textbf{x})\,d\theta = 0 \\[10pt]
\iff & \int_0^\infty [f (x_f^{*} \mid \theta) - f(x_f^{*} \mid \hat{\theta})] \pi(\theta\mid\textbf{x})\,d\theta = 0
\end{align}

Hence, $f(x^{*}_f\mid\theta) = f(x^{*}_f\mid\hat{\theta})$.

Also by the multivariate and unbounded version of the mean value theorem (Apostol analysis book)

$$
\int_0^\infty f (x_f \mid \theta)\pi(\theta\mid\textbf{x})\,d\theta = f(x_f \mid c) \int_0^\infty\pi(\theta\mid\textbf{x}) \, d\theta \text{ for some } c \in [\inf f(x_f \mid \theta), \sup f(x_f\mid\theta)]
$$

Since $\pi(\theta\mid\textbf{x})$ is a posterior distribution and integrates one,

$$
f(x_f\mid c)\int_0^\infty \pi(\theta\mid\textbf{x}) \, d\theta = f(x_f\mid c) = f(x_f\mid \hat{\theta}) \Rightarrow c = \hat{\theta}
$$

But I make an example (the exponential and they do not cut at the MLE). What is wrong here ?

Comment: Does $\widehat\theta$ mean the MLE in all of the places where it appears in the question?

Comment: Yes. It can be a vector also.

Comment: I have several questions about your notation; maybe I'll be back later to deal with those........

Comment: Feel free to ask. When I try to verify this with the exponential distribution and using the jeffreys prior, I just obtain that the cutting point is $\hat{\theta} + \epsilon$ and I want to figure it out what is that $\epsilon$ in general.